# Using wildcards with jsoup Selector

Tags: java, html, dom, css-selectors, jsoup

I'm goin through different webpages for processing using jsoup and the part in the page I want to access is formatted in this way:

```
<section class="featured_name_tabs options9">
```

So typically, to get that, I would just do the following:

```
document.select("section.featured_name_tabs.options9")
```

However, I noticed that the number at the end of the class attribute actually changes, so what I need now is something like (with an asterix at the end):

```
document.select("section.featured_name_tabs.options*")
```

^ But apparently that doesn't work. How do I select that element now that I've discovered that the end of the string isn't always the same? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly with the selector syntax.  You can see this both by looking at the [selector documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) (which supports prefix/suffix/infix/regex matching for attributes and text but not classes), and noting that where attribute [`Evaluator`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Evaluator.html) inner subclasses include regexes, the class `Evaluator` does not.

You'll have to loop over the result of a lesser selection filtering by class name:

```
for (Element e : document.select("section.featured_name_tabs"))
    for (String s : e.className().split(" ")) //multiple classes space-separated
        if (s.startsWith("options"))
            doSomething(e);
```